# SSIS Package stalls when run as a SQL Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Here is the short version of the problem: I have a discrete DTSX file that works fine on our Production server, but doesn't on our new Dev server.

Symptom: When run from a SQL-Server job, the job starts and nothing at all happens, and it never finishes... it just hangs, using very little system resources.

Some info: For Prod, the packages were developed on SQL-Server 2012 and run on an NT 2008 server. The new Dev server is also SQL-Server 2012, but runs on an NT 2012 server (in case that matters). I have duplicated the folder/file structure exactly, including drive name. The package uses an external dtsConfig file, but as I said - the folder/file structure is identical.

The SSIS service, SQL-Server Agent, and my remote login are all the same, and is a member of the server Administrator group on the Dev box. If I copy the command line text from the SQL job and run it in a CMD window using dtexec.exe, the package executes correctly. The job owner is my login, and the "run as" is the SQL-Agent, which - as I mentioned - is the same login. Since everything in the package uses integrated security, everything should be running using the same login whether on the command line or via the SQL-Agent, which should eliminate any user permission/credentials issues.

I tried adding SSIS logging to the package, logging everything I could. When I run the package from the command line, I get a ton of messages in the log. When I run the package via the SQL job, there are no messages at all in the log - nothing.

Whatever is going on, it's not getting far enough into the SSIS package to generate a single log entry. It's just stopping but not exiting or throwing an error. FWIW - I have the same problem with every other package I've tried.

Any ideas are appreciated...

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem. The MS-SQL Server service was using a different login than the SSIS server service and the NT Agent service (it was using a local service account).

Once I changed the MS-SQL Server login to match the others (and restarted the service), the job ran correctly.